# How to send APDU commands to UICC using telephony manager?

Tags: android, android-studio, javacard, telephonymanager, apdu

i am trying to communicate with my java card applet using telephony manager class. Can somebody help me with that?
Basically i want to establish a connection and then send APDU commands to the UICC and vice versa, for which i need to implement the following steps(please correct me if i am wrong) :

1. Use google SDK IccOpenLogicalChannelResponse with applet application id
2. From IccOpenLogicalChannelResponse get open status and logical channel
3. Send apdu by iccTransmitApduLogicalChannel and get String response
4. Android App destroy must  close channel by iccCloseLogicalChannel

P.S - I implemented "Seek for android" - org.simalliance.openmobileapi successfully and my objective is achieved but moving forward to provide support for android devices with an api level more than 21 , i need to implement [Telephony Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) class in android.

Can someone help me with the code level usage of Telephony Manager functions :
iccOpenLogicalChannel, 
iccCloseLogicalChannel, 
iccTransmitApduLogicalChannel, 
iccTransmitApduBasicChannel.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know your app will need `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission or carrier privileges?

Comment: Yeah seems like because the exception i am getting is:

**java.lang.SecurityException: No Carrier Privilege**

at this line in my code

_IccOpenLogicalChannelResponse response = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE).iccOpenLogicalChannel(some byte[]);_

Comment: That is why TelephonyManager is rarely used in real-world apps (for communication with UICC).

Comment: So is there any other approach for this other than TelephonyManager ?

Comment: To byass the *No Carrier Privilege* exception you must sign your app with the same signature of the card. You can sign your app with Android Studio. For example :https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html. The reason is that  Android 5.1 introduced Carrier Privileges (https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/uicc)

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky, but possible.
To get access to your custom AID, first you need to set permission at ARA-M (or ARA-F) where you need to provide your App signature (SHA1 20Bytes) and target custom AID (optional or 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF). Doing so, your mobile App will get carrier-privilege() and then you are good to go.

So, steps:

1. in your smart card or SIM, port a blank ARA-M manually (available in github)
2. Create Android project (don't change keystore as Signature must be maintained). Get SHA 1 (20B) of Signature (256B). Relax, this signature is not dependent on code size, but your development environment. Hence, debug, release and deployment certificate and signature will be different.
3. Send raw APDU by reader to set rules (GlobalPlatform Device Technology Device API Access Control V1.0 or later) using SHA as calculated. Typically it is done by MNO's OTA
4. Now your app will get carrier privilege and you can send APDU to card.

Best of luck.